# How do I call Struct inside a Struct?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

it's a basic question, I'm new to swift, and this is a specific question about Struct Arrays ( Struct inside struct)

I'm trying to have an output (TableView structure with header as section) like this:

[image]

I can do it with Dictionary, 
I'm trying to make arrays in struct

Structs:

```
struct StructSections {
    var sectionName: String!
    var channels: StructChannels
    var collapsed: Bool!

    init(sectionName: String, channels: StructChannels, collapsed: Bool = false) {
        self.sectionName = sectionName
        self.channels = channels
        self.collapsed = collapsed
    }
}

struct StructChannels{
    var channelName: String!
    var streamURL: String!
    var imageURL: String!
}
```

and then I create function to load data

```
func CreateRadioData() {
    var JakartaChannels: [StructChannels] = []
    JakartaChannels = [
        StructChannels(channelName: "Prambors 102.2 FM Jakarta", streamURL: "http://masima.rastream.com/masima-pramborsjakarta", imageURL: "PramborsJakarta"),
        StructChannels(channelName: "I-Radio 89.6 FM Jakarta", streamURL: "http://mra.rastream.com/mra_iradio", imageURL: "IRadioJakarta")
    ]

    var MedanChannels: [StructChannels] = []
    MedanChannels = [
        StructChannels(channelName: "KISS 105 FM Medan", streamURL: "http://live.kissfm-medan.com:8080/kissfm.mp3", imageURL: "KissFMMedan")
    ]



    var Sections:[StructSections] = []
    Sections = [
        StructSections(sectionName: "Jakarta", channels: JakartaChannels),
        StructSections(sectionName: "Medan", channels: MedanChannels)
    ]
}
```

I got error in these codes:

```
 StructSections(sectionName: "Jakarta", channels: JakartaChannels),
 StructSections(sectionName: "Medan", channels: MedanChannels)
```

How to call the structs `JakartaChannels` and `MedanChannels` inside the struct `StructSections` ?

Comment: create array of channels like : var channels: [StructChannels] in StructSections section

Comment: use camelCase for names of variables and functions.

Comment: why do you make a new array `var x: [StructSections] = []`, and then immediately overwrite it with a new array? `x = [a, b, c]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this statement you are passing array of `StructChannels` but it is expected only `StructChannels` ref.

```
StructSections(sectionName: "Jakarta", channels: JakartaChannels)
```

so, create `StructSections` property  channels to array of `StructChannels`.

```
struct StructSections {
var sectionName: String!
var channels: [StructChannels]
var collapsed: Bool!

init(sectionName: String, channels: [StructChannels], collapsed: Bool = false) {
  self.sectionName = sectionName
  self.channels = channels
  self.collapsed = collapsed
}
```

}

Comment: Look at this line. init(sectionName: String, channels: [StructChannels], collapsed: Bool = false) { ..}
 in init params it is also expected [StructChannels].

Comment: one little thing more - You should consider removing the plurals from your struct names.  `StructSection` describes a single section, `sections : [StructSection]` describes an array of sections